# How to post a variable with Ajax.js?

Tags: javascript

Using a XMLHttpRequest with something like

```
xhttp.send('msg=message');
```

Causes a response from a server which returns "message" when asked to respond with req.body.msg.
How do I approach the problem if I want to store the msg value to send in a variable and write the request to post the variable as msg? In other words how to let what comes after msg= be interpreted as variable and not string?

Comment: I removed the tag AJAX cause the question is about concatenating variables, not about AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to insert the variable value into the string

```js
let text = "message";

xhttp.send(`msg=${text}`);
```

You could also just use [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)

```js
let text = "message";

xhttp.send('msg=' + text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please show below code:

```
let text = "message";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params="msg="+${text};
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {
       alert(xhr.responseText);
     }
}
xhr.open('POST', url where you want post data, true);
xhr.send(params);
```